# how to export HTML table in vue.js

Tags: excel, csv, pdf, vue.js

I switched from using jquery to a vue.js frontend framework. I been finding it hard to get a vue.js package to help export HTML table as PDF, Excel and CSV Just like we have in jquery datatable. I also want to be able to print.

Please I appreciate any help